# WCF on Windows Service C# Class null

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a separate WCF service project running in the same solution as my windows service, inside the windows service I populate data from the database into my DataStore class (which happens regularly). The DataStore is in memory so that I can access it whenever and wherever I want, the problem is in my WCF service it is null but not in the windows service...I understand why...the question is how do I access the same class with the same data inside my WCF? There will be multiple connections to the web service so the DataStore needs to have the latest data and not be null.

```
public string GetData(string obj) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        return TestCount = DataStore.Instance.Test.Count.ToString(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        return "Error"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you use operationcontract in your code? and Could you write your code in wcf here ?

Comment: Yes I did, below code is in my Service class

public string GetData(string obj)
        {
            try
            {
                return TestCount = DataStore.Instance.Test.Count.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }

Comment: Sorry not use to the formatting yet...

Comment: Just to clarify, is your question: how do I access a WCF service from a Windows Service, or how to I transmit a class full of data over WCF?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your question exactly what it is that you're trying to achieve; however, if, as I suspect, you're trying to transmit a complex type (class) over WCF, firstly, as @Amir suggests, you'll need the the [Operation or DataContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) decorators - I notice these are not present in your sample.  Depending on the complexity of your data transmission, you might need the [KnownType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types) decorator, too.

Assuming that you are passing around complex types, it may benefit you to separate these models into their own, distinct, assembly.

Some time ago, I wrote a [short article](http://pmichaels.net/2015/01/14/returning-an-unknown-interface-from-a-wcf-service/) on passing around a dummy interface, for times when you might not know exactly what it is that you want to transmit.

It's also worth considering whether there is any value in having a data cache inside a WCF service.  If you are using the default instancing, then you will not retain this cache from one call to the next.